# Difference b/w Caratheodory measurable set and Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

I got a little confused with the relationship of those two concepts while reading [a text of J.K. Hunter](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m206/measure_notes.pdf) in which he's defined them as follows;

### Caratheodory measurable sets

[image]

### Lebesgue measurable sets

[image]

## Question

In Thr 2.4 on the text, we also studied that Lebesgue outer measure is an outer measure. So, now, I can't seem to figure out what the def of Lebesgue measurable sets adds to the def of Caratheodory measurable sets..

Can anyone help me with it?

### Supplementary

I also went through a couple of MathSE articles regarding this but no luck yet...

- [Lebesgue measurable implies caratheodory measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3945404/lebesgue-measurable-implies-caratheodory-measurable)
- [Proving the *Caratheodory Criterion* for *Lebesgue Measurability*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064678/proving-the-caratheodory-criterion-for-lebesgue-measurability)
- [Intuition behind the definition of a measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485815/intuition-behind-the-definition-of-a-measurable-set)
- [Question about 'inner measure equals outer measure $\iff$ measurable set'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104419/question-about-inner-measure-equals-outer-measure-iff-measurable-set)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability

Comment: The definition 2.10 only says that "Lebesgue-measurable" is a shorthand for "Carathéodory-measurable with respecto to the Lebesgue outer measure".

Comment: The sets that satisfy the Caratheodory measurability condition form a $\sigma$-algebra, exactly what you want to do integration on abstract spaces. The utility of the construction is that any premeasure on an algebra of subsets of a space $X$ induces an outer measure, to which the construction then applies. And premeasures and algebras are easier to define (and visualize). For example, on $\mathbb R$ take the algebra of $\textit{finite}$ unions of intervals and define a premeasure on these as sums of lengths of disjoint intervals. From this, Lebesgue measure follows more or less automatically.

Comment: Definition 2.8 does not seem right. It never says what $E$ is.

Comment: Lebesgue measurable sets are just Caratheodory measurable sets with respect to the Lebesgue outer measure.

Comment: @azif00, and Ramiro. Thank you! "Lebesgue measurable sets are just Caratheodory measurable sets with respect to the Lebesgue outer measure" makes sense!!

Comment: @Matematleta, thank you for the detailed explanation! It's a bit advanced for me since I haven't learnt premeasure yet but will come back this later!!

Comment: @311411, I think it was defined before the Def but other answers already cleared my answer so no worries!

Comment: Rowing: good luck to you studying M.T. It can be daunting, but it sure is nifty stuff.